# How do you make a combination for this problem?

Tags: word-problem

> You have $11$ bags which you can load with money. In the first bag,
>   there's \$$1$(cannot be changed), and you will be asked to load these bags with money I want between $1-2000$ (Which is like $1447$, $1550$, $27$ or anything other, so it doesn't matter.) **Note that the total sum of the money you load will be equal to $2000$ and you need to fill each bags**.

The thing made me confused is can we give every money he wants? For example, I'll pick a random value, which is $1447$.

$$1 / 2 / 3 / 4 / 5 / 10 / 25 / 50 / 100/800/1000 = \$2000$$ 
I could try giving him

$$ 1000 + 100 + 50 + 25 + 10 + 5 + 4 + 2 + 1 \neq \$1447 $$

Which is not equal to the value I selected.

As you can see, I couldn't be able to give that money. This question should have an easy solution I'm missing! Can you take a look since you are advanced?

My Kindest Regards!

Comment: Please state the word problem *exactly as is*.

Comment: @idk That's it. You have $11$ bags and you load all the bags with money. In the first bag, there's \$$1$ which you cannot change.

Comment: "As a summary, you will be able to give every money I want."  What if you ask of a hundred million gazillion dollars?  "Also, the sum of the money you load will be equal to \$2000".  So you can't ask for more than \$2000? Because I don't have more than $2000$?

Comment: @fleablood It won't ask sorry for miswriting. I'm editing it now. The value he can request can be between $1-2000$. He cannot ask you of a hundred million gazillion dollars. So, currently trying on it and writing combinations.

Comment: So... I fill the second bag with \$1999 and leave the rest of the bags empty.  You ask for \$1447.  So I reach into the second bag and pull out \$1447?  Simple.  Please, actually state *everything* the problem actually states.  Obviously you are making assumptions that you are not stating.

Comment: Perhaps you should point out you can only give him full bags of money....

Comment: See the new edit.

Comment: Please choose a more expressive title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to put \$3 in the third bag. If you are asked for exactly \$3, you could hand over the first two bags. Thus you could put \$4 in the third bag. Similarly, with bags containing \$1, \$2, and \$4 you can obtain any dollar amount between \$1 and \$7. So the fourth bag should contain \$8.

Proceed in this manner, and the dollar amounts in the first 10 bags will be $$ \$ 1 , \$2, \$4, \$8, \$16, \$32, \$64, \$128, \$256, \$512.$$

You can use these bags to make any dollar amount between \$1 and \$1023.

Now place the remaining \$977 into the eleventh bag. You can make any dollar amount between \$977 and \$2000 using the eleventh bag and an appropriate selection of bags between 1 and 10.

Comment: However, I can't get $1200$ with this combination. What would we do? and note that this combination isn't equal to $2000$.

Comment: $977  + 128 + 64 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 1200$.

Comment: $1 + 2+ 4+ 8+16+32+64+128+256+512 + 977 = 2000$.

Comment: @fleablood Does that combination support every values?

Comment: "You can use these bags to make any dollar amount between \$1 and \$1023."  So apparently Umberto P thinks so. But what do *you* think?

Comment: @fleablood And I can't get $95$ with that combination. It seems like we're going with by multiplying the values. So, we've to change the last number.

Comment: $95 = 64 + 31$ and $31 = 16+ 8+4+2 + 1$ so $95 = 64 + 16 + 8+4+2+1$.

Comment: @fleablood That is Unbelievable! Can you please explain how you found it? I'm very very excited to learn how you solved this.

Comment: @Flisch: did you realize that the binary representation of each number in $[1,2000]$ has at most $11$ bits?

Comment: @Flisch you can use the "greedy algorithm": take the largest bag less than or equal to the amount you need, subtract that amount, and repeat.

Comment: To get any number  n > 977 do 977 + (n - 977).  To do any number n-977 = m > 1023 do 512 + (m - 512).  To do any number m-512 = k > 512 to 256 + (k - 256).  To do and number k-256 = j > 128 do 128 + (j-128)  ... and so on.

Comment: So, Could I solve this question by using greedy algorithm? and I still didn't get how to.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask Umberto and not me?  *HE*s the one who found it.  This is actually quite well known.  It's binary representation.

Comment: @UmbertoP. What do you mean by ''greedy algorithm'' and can you explain in detail?

Comment: All numbers $n$ are between $2^k \le n < 2^{k+1}$ for some $k$.  Figure that out and give that bag.  Then you have to figure out how to give $n - 2^k$.  Well, $2^m \le n-2^k < 2^{m+1}$ for some $m$.  So give *that* bag... and keep going.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should fill the each bag as full as you can stuff it, yet still be able to deliver on all of the orders less than that bag size.  This will allow you to fill the largest number of orders with the fewest number of bags.

The first bag has $\$1.$
What if you are asked to deliver $\$2$?  You better have a bag with 2 bucks in it.  This is a more efficient use of the limited resource (the limited number of bags) than having a second bag with $\$1.$

What if you are asked to deliver $\$3$? Easy, give bags $1$ and $2.$

What if you are asked to deliver $\$4$? Can't do that with what you have already allocated.  You will need to fill another bag, and fill it with $4$ dollars.

With bags 1,2,3 you can fill orders up to $7$ dollars, but you can't fill the $8$ dollar order.

Have you spotted a pattern yet?  Can you prove that by this pattern, you can fill any size order less than $\$2000$?

Comment: Have you filled each bags?

Comment: " You better have a bag with 2 bucks in it."  Or a second bag with 1 buck in it.  Perhaps we should spend a nonasecond pointing out that a bag with 2 bucks can do everything a bag with 1 buck can but more so that is a better strategy.

Comment: @fleablood fair point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be like that;
1,2,4,8,16,32,128,256,512,1024

But since you said that you need a sum of 2000, you can make 973 instaed of 1024.
you can also play around with the other numbers.
The key is, that you should choose the next number to be 1 bigger than the sum of all numbers that you have so far, or less than that, but not bigger.

for example, 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,490,999.

Comment: $1 + .... + 512 = 1023$ and $2000 - 1023 = 977$.  Not $973$.  Minor nitpick.